# OpenGL rendering a list of GL_POINTS

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I am currently trying to render a list of points on the screen but all I get is the following, a single dot which moves with my camera and stays in the centre of the screen.

[image]

The list of points generated change with each frame and defined in world space coordinates. I want to know where I am going wrong with the code below and what are the best practices for drawing a dynamic list of points like this without using immediate mode calls. Most  online resources refer to glBegin() and glEnd() when drawing points.

```
 void RenderPoints(const CamInfo & camInfo, const std::vector<vec4>& listofpoints )
{
Shader->Use();
Shader->setUniform("MVP",camInfo.proj * camInfo.view);
Shader->setUniform("Color",glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,1.0f));
glGenVertexArrays( 1, &M_VAO );
glBindVertexArray( M_VAO );


glGenBuffers( 1, &M_VBO );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, M_VBO ); 
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, listofpoints.size()*sizeof(glm::vec4), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0,  listofpoints.size()*sizeof(glm::vec4), (const GLvoid*)(&listofpoints[0]) );
GLuint pos_location = glGetAttribLocation(Shader->GetProgramID(), "position");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos_location ); 
glVertexAttribPointer( pos_location, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
glGenBuffers(1, &M_IBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, M_IBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertex_indices.size()*sizeof(GLuint), (const GLvoid*)(&m_vertex_indices[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glPointSize(10.0f);
glBindVertexArray(M_VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, M_IBO);
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS,m_vertex_indices.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,&m_vertex_indices);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
Shader->Disable();

}
```

Comment: You should debug more. You set color to be Cyan (0,1,1) but the dot is white. That's puzzling. Maybe your scale or matrices are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a buffer for your vertex indices, but passing the address your index array (or perhaps the address of an std::vector?) to `glDrawElements`. When a buffer is bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` the fourth argument of `glDrawElements` is an offset into that buffer, so in your case you should pass 0:

```
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, m_vertex_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

By unbinding the vertex buffer *before* you unbind the vertex array you're telling the vertex array not to record the appropriate buffer.  When you unbind the vertex array with `glBindVertexArray(0)` the state machine should be in exactly the state (with regard to vertex buffers) you would have it when you call `glDrawElements`.  That means that you have no vertex buffer bound during your draw call, so it's probably using random values (and probably generating an error if you check with `glGetError`.

Try swapping those two lines.